# How to know if file exsits ina Samba share

Tags: bash, shell, unix, samba

I wrote a  shellscript  as follows, to check for a file in a samba share:

```
 date_gen=$(date --date="3 days ago" +"%-Y%m%d")
 fileName=${date_gen}"_Combined Reg Report.xlsx"
 if [ ! -f smb://nfs/carboard/"${fileName}" -U  ]
 then
    echo "File does not exist in Bash"
else
  echo ${fileName}
fi
exit 1
```

Can someone please help me what is wrong with this, I am always getting  "File does not exist in Bash". File is there in the folder.

Thanks,
Art

Comment: Is the share mounted on the system? Accessing it directly via the shell is not possible otherwise and requires external tools

Comment: Well I am able to use the command smget and copy file from shared folder to unix server. So I think share is mounted. Does this help?

Comment: If you're using `smbget` then it means that the share is not mounted.

Answer (score 2):

You should check if it's mounted and then check for the file

```
if mount | grep -q /nfs/cardboard
then
    if [[ ! -f /nfs/cardboard/"${fileName}" ]]
    then
        ...
    fi
else
    echo "not mounted"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking the existence of a file with `smbclient`:

```sh
filename="$(date --date='3 days ago' '+%Y%m%d')_Combined Reg Report.xlsx"

if smbclient -A smbauth.conf '//nfs/carboard' -c "ls \"$filename\"" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo the file exists
else
    echo the file is not there
fi
```

where `smbauth.conf` is a file storing your credentials in the following format:

```
username=myuser
password=mypassword
domain=MYDOMAIN
```

I don't know how escaping exactly works with `smbclient` (it seems like some characters like `"` are impossible to escape), but in your case, double-quoting is enough.